# Remove list entries from the beginning using lambda

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have breadcrumbs from a website and I want to remove all "Home" entries from the beginning with a lambda expression.

Something like:

```
lambda v: v[1:] if v and v[0] == 'Home' else v
```

But I want to remove multiples, not just the first one, and only from the beginning, so that:

```
['Home', 'Home', 'Home and Garden', 'Home', 'Kitchen']
```

becomes:

```
['Home and Garden', 'Home', 'Kitchen']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this is what you were going for with your `lambda`:

```
>>> F = lambda v: F(v[1:]) if v and v[0] == 'Home' else v
>>> L = ['Home', 'Home', 'Home and Garden', 'Home', 'Kitchen']
>>> F(L)
['Home and Garden', 'Home', 'Kitchen']
```

However that will be inefficient and Python already has tools for this:

```
>>> from itertools import dropwhile
>>> L = ['Home', 'Home', 'Home and Garden', 'Home', 'Kitchen']
>>> list(dropwhile(lambda x: x == 'Home', L))
['Home and Garden', 'Home', 'Kitchen']
```

Alternatively:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> from operator import eq
>>> from itertools import dropwhile
>>> L = ['Home', 'Home', 'Home and Garden', 'Home', 'Kitchen']
>>> list(dropwhile(partial(eq, "Home"), L))
['Home and Garden', 'Home', 'Kitchen']
```

Which should be faster, bur requires a few more imports

Comment: That's great, thanks. My lambda turned out to be: `lambda L: list(dropwhile(partial(eq, "Home"), L))`.